How to read floats from XLSX file with OpenXLSX
I'm trying to read a set of data from my Excel file.

I am able to read the integers from the first column:
const auto sdf = sheet.cell(fmt::format("A{}", rowIndex)).value().get<int>();

I am also able to read the strings from the second column:
const auto sdf = sheet.cell(fmt::format("B{}", rowIndex)).value().get<std::string>();

but I can't figure out how to read the values in column C into doubles.
I tried:
const auto sdf = sheet.cell(fmt::format("C{}", rowIndex)).value().get<double>();

but that results in termination:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'OpenXLSX::XLValueTypeError'
  what():  XLCellValue object does not contain the requested type.

Would anybody know what to do? How do I read a float from my file?
Edit
I also check some tests from the OpenXLSX repo. I don't find any differences.

You should catch value type exceptions anyway otherwise simple typo in input file will terminate your universe. Perhaps there are integers 1 only formatted as "1.00".

@ÖöTiib Jesus, you are correct. Reading as integers works. The first few rows are really integers, the last few become doubles. I'll have to take care of that separately I guess.

Ther's an open issue on GitHub (OpenXLSX repository) with a proposal fix (https://github.com/troldal/OpenXLSX/issues/196).
